# Validating FB CAPI

Tags: facebook, facebook-conversions-api

I'm trying to audit and validate my server-side events being sent to FB CAPI for accuracy and completeness, however I'm having trouble actually mimicking a server-side event in CAPI. I've tried to make an API call replicating my server-side purchase event through postman and graph API. Both are showing me an error message that says: "This Ads API request is not allowed for apps with development access level (Development access is by default for all apps, please request for upgrade). Make sure that the access token belongs to a user that is both admin of the app and admin of the ad account".

I have admin access to my ads account and to the app, however the app has standard access. When I try to request advanced access for the app for ads-management services, FB tells me that I need to make XXX+ API calls first and have an error rate < X%. I'm so confused how can I test that my event is working properly? Any one have ideas?